# I think someone has hacked my HTC Droid DNA. How can i check and be sure?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean

My device has been doing lots of crazy things, like uninstalling apps, installing apps that aren't in `Google play store`. I had questions about it yesterday, but the ones that started last night seem more important.
I went to settings to see what apps were running and to check only the newly `do not disturb` app that popped up and noticed I have 2-3 of each app. `3 calendars, 3 tasks, 2 Facebook apps`, one has some lettering next
To it that the other don't, can't remember what they are. I know these weren't there a few weeks ago because I was trying to find my camera and gallery that were installed on this device, but have vanished. What can I do to track down where they went, as well as who did this?

Comment: First, make sure that there's nobody playing with your phone without your knowledge. Second, multiple running processes of the same app is actually normal, *unless* the apps are similar but different. Third, just for clarification, what phone model & Android version are you using? Are you rooted (if don't understand and can't answer it, then probably not)? Did you install suspicious apps? (e.g. I heard "Super Flashlight" or similar is suspicious)

Comment: Are there any apps you've installed shortly before this started? Maybe even from "other sources"? In that case, you might have "hacked yourself" by installing a malicious app (which from your description seems the most likely thing). To really "clean up the mess" then without much background knowledge, you might have to [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) your device – which as a side-effect would mean you're losing all your app-data and the apps you've installed. There might be other solutions, but they are a little more complicated to apply.

Comment: Have you installed antivirus software?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the network **Input-Output** if, there is a hacker or suspicious app installed and its using of your Internet Connection or Internet Bandwidth.

Most of the android hack tools, need `Internet Access` for **Remote Access** just for remote hacking or remote connection.so,

the best think is, you need to install the **Packet Sniffers** or **Network Sniffers** for find the suspicious Process.with :

> [**Capturing mobile phone traffic**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570093/4409113)

and other Programs ***(In android - Apk App)*** if you can install an app.

Also, as `Andrew.T` said, you can check the phone for suspicious apps and delete them for prevention access of hacker.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not something you can ask a beginner to do. This kind of analysis would require some "expert knowledge": What kind of traffic is "good", what is "bad" – and how to tell one from the other? Most apps access the network for one or another reason. And it requires some knowledge to tell the bad guys apart.